# Vue Element UI dynamically changes el-select color

Tags: vuejs2, element-ui

I tried to modify el-select to match the color of el-option.
The methods I search on the Internet always require me to modify the style scoped . It is a static method and cannot be changed dynamically.

[image: Example: My expectation is when selecting "WIP" in the options will turn it into a yellow label in el-select.]

My expectation is when I select "WIP" in the options, it will become a yellow label in el-select according to the color in the options.

---

The following is a rough demo I created in Codesandbox.

https://codesandbox.io/s/dynamically-change-el-select-color-based-on-status-v0u8d?file=/src/views/Editor.vue

Your kind assistance will be greatly appreciated, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a ton of research, finally I found the solution. [image]

The following is a rough demo I created in Codesandbox.
https://codesandbox.io/s/dynamically-change-el-select-color-based-on-status-v2-od8gn?file=/src/views/Editor.vue

I'm not sure if this is the best method, but this method has solved my problem. If you have a better solution, welcome to provide here.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You could set the class of the `el-select` based on that you could color the input value based on the selected value

```
<el-select
          v-model="scope.row.status"
          :class="getStatusColorClass(scope.row.status)"
          placeholder="Select"
        >
          <el-option
            v-for="(status, index) in statusList"
            :key="index"
            :label="status.name"
            :value="status.id"
          >
            <span :style="{ color: status.color }">{{ status.name }}</span>
          </el-option>
        </el-select>
```

JS:

```
  methods: {
    getStatusColorClass(id) {
      if (!id) {
        return {};
      }

      return this.statusList.find(status => status.id === id).name;
    }
  }
```

SCSS:

```
<style lang="scss">
.Approved input {
  color: #00A86B;
}
.Retake input {
  color: #ED2939;
}
.WIP input {
  color: #FCE205;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your method is valid, but not the same as I expected. You can check [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dynamically-change-el-select-color-based-on-status-v0u8d?file=/src/views/Editor.vue), my option status color is obtained from the database.
      statusList: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "Approved",
          color: "#00A86B",
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "Retake",
          color: "#ED2939",
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: "WIP",
          color: "#FCE205",
        },
      ],

Comment: @Coleone element-ui doesn't provide any property or something to manipulate the the styling of the element itself. If that is where you are looking for I've to dissappoint you because there isn't any. An alternative is to hack it a little, use the prefix to show the value + color and hide de actual value with css

Comment: Hi @dreijntjens, can you provide me with detailed information about "use the prefix to show the value + color and hide de actual value with CSS"?